# 2 arguments missing but method works

Tags: django

Could you help me understand what is going on here. The question is about the error in the traceback. The failure is just as the illustration. And what I would like to illustrate that the function works.

Well, I was told that 2 positional arguments: 'view_instance' and 'address' are missing.

But the method really has taken those 2 positional arguments and worked happily till its logical end. In the interactive playing I show that I can catch the arguments transmitted.

Why does error appear? Thank you in advance for your help.

ADDED LATER:

Well, this seems to be because of the 'test_' beginning of the function.

Without "test" it works (def anonymous_user_redirected_to_login_page(self, view_instance, address):).

**/photoarchive/general/tests.py**

```
class GeneralTest(TestCase):

    def test_anonymous_user_redirected_to_login_page(self, view_instance, address):
        pdb.set_trace()
        request = RequestFactory().get(address)
        request.user = AnonymousUser()
        response = view_instance(request)        
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertEqual(response['location'], '/accounts/login/')

    def test_anonymous_user_from_home_page_redirected_to_login_page(self):
        view_instance = HomePageView.as_view()
        address = '/'
        self.test_anonymous_user_redirected_to_login_page(view_instance, address)
```

**Traceback**

```
(photoarchive) michael@michael:~/workspace/photoarchive/photoarchive$ python manage.py test general
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
FE
======================================================================
ERROR: test_anonymous_user_redirected_to_login_page (general.tests.GeneralTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError: test_anonymous_user_redirected_to_login_page() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'view_instance' and 'address'

======================================================================
FAIL: test_anonymous_user_from_home_page_redirected_to_login_page (general.tests.GeneralTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/workspace/photoarchive/photoarchive/general/tests.py", line 29, in test_anonymous_user_from_home_page_redirected_to_login_page
    self.test_anonymous_user_redirected_to_login_page(view_instance, address)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/photoarchive/photoarchive/general/tests.py", line 23, in test_anonymous_user_redirected_to_login_page
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
AssertionError: 200 != 302

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.002s

FAILED (failures=1, errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

**Interactive playing:**

```
(photoarchive) michael@michael:~/workspace/photoarchive/photoarchive$ python manage.py test general
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
> /home/michael/workspace/photoarchive/photoarchive/general/tests.py(20)test_anonymous_user_redirected_to_login_page()
-> request = RequestFactory().get(address)
(Pdb) view_instance
<function HomePageView at 0x7faa0f76fea0>
(Pdb) address
'/'
(Pdb)
```

Comment: That might be because  when you run them tests, only methods starting with `test` are executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test_anonymous_user_redirected_to_login_page()` method is treated by unittest framework as a test method, because its name starts with `test`. The framework tries to execute it, but is not passing any arguments to it (test methods don't normally take any arguments). However, the method requires them, hence the error.

If this method is only a helper method to be called from the other method, name it so that it doesn't start with `test`, e.g. `_test_anonymous_user_redirected_to_login_page()`.

Note that the traceback is not related to this problem. The traceback simply shows where the other test method failed at an assertion. That is, the other test method runs correctly (both in unittest run and in your interactive session).